# How to describe this using python re?

Tags: python, matching, python-re

I creating esoteric programming language and I want to realize this structure to print text:

```
   !(some-text)
```

This structure must write text in parentheses and end up with *)*.

But for some reason this structure end up only when find newline. I think it happened 'cause dot matching any symbol except *\n*. I tried to create condition using *(?!...)* but this wasn't working too. Eventually I don't know how to match all symbols without *\n* and *)*.

Below I have attached the full code of the token table so that you find errors in it and suggest ways to fix them.
Thanks in advance for any help!

```
token_table = [
(r'[ \t\n]+', None),
(r'!\((?!\)).*\)', 'PRINTSTR'), # This is not working
(r'[-]?[0-9]+', 'INT'),
(r'(?!!|\?|\(|\)|:|<|>|\+).*', None),
(r'!', 'PASS'),
(r'\?', 'IF'),
(r'\(', 'LPAR'),
(r'\)', 'RPAR'),
(r'>', 'INPUT'),
(r'<', 'PRINT'),
(r':', 'GOTO'),
(r'\+', 'ADD'), ]
```

Comment: [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `.`, use `[^)]` to match any character other than `)`. This will include newlines.

```
(r'!\([^)]*\)', 'PRINTSTR')
```